# How to execute a Bash script from Github?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, downloads, git

Say this I have the following file `my_cool_file.sh` in a Git repository in *Github* (or *BitBucket* for that matter) named `my_cool_repo`. The file is a script used to install ConfigServer's well known CSF-LFD software:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/src
rm -fv csf.tgz
wget https://download.configserver.com/csf.tgz
tar -xzf csf.tgz
cd csf
sh install.sh
sed -i "s/TESTING = "1"/TESTING = "0"/g" /etc/csf/csf.conf
csf -r
perl /usr/local/csf/bin/csftest.pl
# sh /etc/csf/uninstall.sh
```

How can one execute this Bash script (a `.sh` file) directly from Github, via command line?

Comment: As you are putting this script up on github, consider `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as your hash-bang for better portability.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Load the file (make sure you use the raw file, otherwise you load the HTML page!) with `wget` using its exact URL and then pipe the output to `bash`:

Here's an example with clarifications:

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<project>/<branch>/<path>/<file> | bash
```

From the [manpage for the `wget` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/wget):

> ```
>    -O file
>    --output-document=file
>        The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
>        will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as
>        file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link
>        conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)
>
>        Use of -O is not intended to mean simply "use the name file instead
>        of the one in the URL;" rather, it is analogous to shell
>        redirection: wget -O file http://foo is intended to work like wget
>        -O - http://foo > file; file will be truncated immediately, and all
>        downloaded content will be written there.
> ```

So outputting to `-` will actually write the files content to STDOUT and then you simply pipe it to `bash` or whatever shell you prefer. If you script needs `sudo` rights you need to do `sudo bash` at the end so the line becomes:

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<project>/<branch>/<path>/<file> | sudo bash
```

Comment: What about params? Let's say the piped script optionally handles $1, would there be a way to pass it in?

Answer (score 7):

If your script has user entries like `read user_input` try this:

> bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/project/branch/path/file.sh)

The `-s` parameter don't show download progress.

Answer (score 0):

You may use following command to pass in the parameters

```
bash -s
```

Found it here: 
[passing parameters to bash when executing a script fetched by curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642915/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your bash script to be able to use pipes, use `bash -c`:

```bsh
cat myfile.txt | \
bash -c "$(curl http://example.com/script.sh )" -s arg1 arg2
```

You can also use it with `wget -O` (as in @videonauth 's answer)

Example [usage](https://github.com/sohale/snippets/blob/master/bash-magic/bash-from-url.sh):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export MYURL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sohale/snippets/master/bash-magic/add-date.sh"
curl http://www.google.com | \
bash -c "$(curl -L $MYURL )" -s "       >>>>> next line "
```

If you use bit.ly to shorten the url, don't forget the `-L`.